# ExtJs Form Panel - Hide Field event?

Tags: javascript, extjs, formpanel

I have a form panel..

and items..

```
        {
            name: 'FINGERPRINT_REQUIRED',
            xtype: 'hidden'
        },
        {
            name: '<%=ParamC.FINGERPRINT%>',
            fieldLabel: '<spring:message htmlEscape="true" code="EntitlementsHome.FINGERPRINT"/>',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }
```

What is the best approach to hiding the FINGERPRINT field.. based on FINGERPRINT_REQUIRED value?

Is there a listener that I can use before the form is rendered? New to ExtJS so please forgive my ignorance :)

Running 3.x -

any help is appreciated -

Comment: Who/what sets the value of the `FINGERPRINT_REQUIRED `? Of course there is a listener for afterrender: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel-event-render

Comment: What are you using your hidden field for ? Can you expose what are you trying to solve ? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: the data is coming from an XMLStore.. It's really a pretty simple form.. certain datasets require the user to enter a fingerprint text value.. others don't -- I'd like to hide the field if it's not required (rather than just allow it to pass validation)

Comment: looking at the afterrender/render and i don't think I can accomplish what I need there.. appears to fire once for the form.. but i'm reusing the same form for multiple datasets on the page.. some of those require the fingerprint .. some don't.. i'm firing the form from a cell in a grid

Comment: You have hosts of events in ExtJs. You also have a *change* event.

Comment: thanks lorenz.. I just can't seem to find the right on on the right object.. Seems like a fairly common usecase -

Comment: Can we see the code that causes this form to be rendered/displayed? How is it determined whether this field should be displayed or not?